# Can't Launch Tensorboard (Error on request)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to launch Tensorboard from my terminal using this command:

`tensorboard --logdir=/home/anneke/project/surf/tensorflow/cnn4sft --host=127.0.0.1`

but it shows this error:

```
TensorBoard 1.5.1 at http://127.0.0.1:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
E0725 16:26:52.340939 Thread-1 _internal.py:88] Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 261, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 224, in write
    self.send_response(code, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 332, in send_response
    self.log_request(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 356, in log_request
    color = termcolor.colored
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'colored'
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

After I checked the `termcolor` package, it seems had some installation crash.

So, I uninstall the `termcolor` package using `sudo pip uninstall termcolor` and reinstall it and also delete the cache using `sudo pip install --no-cache-dir termcolor` .

Now it can execute and launch the tensorboard in the browser.